# Expedience or Expediency

Tags: nouns

I have been using the word 'expedience' for years.  Today I checked one of the Oxford online dictionaries, and was surprised that it does not have this word! It only had  'expediency' as a noun form.

Is 'expedience' a word? Is it obsolete? Is 'expediency' preferred?

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expedient?q=expedience#expedient__12

Comment: The OED is a lie!

Comment: @Oldcat Where do you look  for the definition of *lie*?

Comment: Your discovery of this fact is interesting sure, but what's your question?

Comment: @Kris's link is to the "cut-down" version dictionary from Oxford University Press. The (relatively uncommon, dated, bordering on archaic) noun ***expedience*** in [the *full* OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66474?redirectedFrom=expedience#eid) gives three definitions - two are marked "obsolete", the third *(interested motives or considerations)* is noted as normally used only in the plural (if at all). So I think this question is Off Topic because it's based on a false premise (that the noun usage is part of normal English today).

Answer (score 5):

The word "[expedience](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expedience)" appears to have arrived first, in 1548. It meant both "with haste" and "the quality of being suited to the purpose at hand".

The word "[expediency](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expediency)" is dated to 1597, but with the same meaning. It appears that "expedience" is obsolete, while "expediency" is still in use. Interestingly, the definition of the term as "with haste" is also considered obsolete. Expediency is now correctly used solely as a noun for "suitable means".

Meanwhile, the term "expedience" is still used colloquially in our language today with the obsolete definition of "with haste". As in the case of, "Deliver this package to the customer with expedience!" This appears to be the only common usage of this term; however, "with haste" would be the correct way of saying it.

Both "expedience" and "expediency" have the [following etymological source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=expedient): "late 14c., "advantageous, fit, proper," from Old French expedient (14c.) or directly from Latin expedientem (nominative expediens) "beneficial," present participle of expedire "make fit or ready, prepare" (see expedite). The noun meaning "a device adopted in an exigency, a resource" is from 1650s. Related: Expediential; expedientially (both 19c.)"

Comment: Thank you.  I confirm :Online Oxford dictionary does not have the word 'expedience', but online Cambridge dictionary does not have the word 'expediency'.  How about that?  I guess it's old like me, prefers the word 'expedience'.

Comment: I think the OED and Fowler are incorrect about this definition, at least in their modern American usage. In every single example I've ever seen, there is a clear sense that something expedient is unadorned and practical to a fault -- not merely useful or appropriate. You simply cannot use expediency/expedience to mean merely "suitable means" (OED) or "fitness, suitability, advantage" (Fowler), as in, say, "The congressional committee carefully and methodically considered the evidence with all the expediency/expedience at their disposal." This sentence is nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

[Oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expedient?q=expedience#expedient__12) Online:

> **expedience**
>   noun

[Fowler](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=XvSAl4Ng8SYC&pg=PT257&lpg=PT257&dq=%22expedience%22%20%22expediency%22%20fowlers&source=bl&ots=YcNGxpP3IB&sig=Wj8iqeanGtrerlXhaQJ11WpuR8w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2y0QU_ihNM2HiQfPg4DAAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22expedience%22%20%22expediency%22%20fowlers&f=false) states that both are valid; *expediency* more common.

> **expedience, expediency**.
>   Both forms are in use in the meaning 'fitness, suitability, advantage', although *expediency* is much more common (three times more, according to the evidence of the OEC). The rhythm of the sentence often determines which is used:
>   *The present mentality on the island emphasises short cuts, expedience and disdain for professional standard --New Scientist, 1991* /
>   *At the time there was a case to be made for the new policy satisfying the demands both of expediency and humanity --K. Tidrick, 1992.*

I like Fowler's observation on rhythm of the sentence.

Anne Bronte, *The Tenant of Wildfell Hall* [45-1](http://brontea.thefreelibrary.com/The-Tenant-of-Wildfell-Hall/45-1#expedience)

> "It is no question of mere **expedience** with me; it is a question of life and death."

### [EDIT]

Jacky Wong
[Dalian Wanda: An Offer That Makes Shareholders Want to Move On](http://www.wsj.com/articles/dalian-wanda-an-offer-that-makes-shareholders-want-to-move-on-1464608868) The Walls Street Journal, May 30, 2016
Plan to delist Wanda’s commercial-property unit so soon after IPO reeks of **expedience** rather than long-term value creation (emphasis added)

Leonard Pitts Jr., [When expedience feels like wisdom](http://www.seattletimes.com/opinion/when-expedience-feels-like-wisdom/), The Seattle Times

Froma Harrop, [Confessions of a Former Dead-Ender](http://www.realclearpolitics.com/articles/2016/05/31/confessions_of_a_former_dead-ender_130719.html), May 31, 2016. RealClearPolitics
It all seemed so unfair. Hillary the workhorse had labored at putting together a coherent health reform plan. The glamorous Obama floated by. Political **expedience** prompted him to oppose an individual mandate -- unpopular because it forced everyone to obtain coverage but absolutely essential for universal health care. (emphasis added)

Mike Selvey, [Alex Hales shines as England survive Sri Lanka’s catching masterclass](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2016/may/27/england-sri-lanka-second-test-day-one-report), The Guardian, 27 May 2016
There was a missed opportunity for James Vince too, victim, for the second time, of his own enthusiasm for stroke play over **expedience**. (emphasis added)

*Expedience* is not even dead: [nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expedience%2Cexpediency&year_start=2000&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpedience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexpediency%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thanks for this; it is striking that Fowler's example sentences (great examples) clash with its definition, which is simply wrong. Your recent examples affirm my sense that expedience is very much in current use.